# How to repair Geometric Network in Versioned ArcSDE Geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning, geometric-network

Our Versioned ArcSDE workflow has a feature dataset with Geometric Network in the parent (Default), which users derive in their own versions.  It is now observed that in some versions, the geometric network is no longer valid and does not abide connectivity rules.

- How can we repair connectivity/enable Geometric Network again in these versions?
- Or should we do this on the default dataset, rather than in user versions?
- What are the tools which may help us to retrieve the Geometric Network ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience working with Geometric Networks and the Esri brain trust, The goal should be to fix in DEFAULT and reconcile to all the versions. 
The proven method is as follows:

1. Reconcile/Post/Delete as many versions as possible. Those you cannot post, reconcile.
2. Fix the connectivity errors in the DEFAULT version. Depending on your ArcGIS Version there are different tools: [READ THIS](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geometric-networks/about-repairing-network-connectivity.htm)
3. Run the [Verify And Repair Geometric Network Connectivity](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/verify-and-repair-geometric-network-connectivity.htm) Geoprocessing tool. First Report then repair. This should also be done against the DEFAULT version. Again, depending on your errors You may need the exhaustive check, in which case you need to fishnet your extent into manageable sizes and iterate over the fishnet.

   ```
   fc = "ENTER FC file path"
   network = "ENTER path to Network"
   log = r'C\temp\output.txt'
   rows = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,"SHAPE@")
   x=0
   for row in rows:
       x+=1
       extent = arcpy.Geometry.buffer(row[0],15)
       output= log.split(".")[0]+ str(x) + ".txt"
       arcpy.VerifyAndRepairGeometricNetworkConnectivity_management(network,log,"VERIFY_AND_REPAIR","EXHAUSTIVE_CHECK",extent)
   ```
4. Reconcile all the versions again in recommended order and in favor of PARENT. Depending on your errors you may need to reconcile by OBJECT for reconcile to succeed

Comment: I like this approach, but thinking about my own network, I'd be afraid of 1) taking hours if not days to finish, or 2) tapping out my computer's memory. I just tried making a 15ft x 15ft city-wide fishnet polygon for another project, and I can't even do a spatial select without running out of memory. How big of a fishnet were you using, and did you make it with polylines or polygons?

Comment: The fishnet size depends on the density of features in your network. On the order of 5 to 10k features per grid... Some trial and error will be necessary.